# How to draw a sphere in matlab and patch it in a 3D plot?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a 3D plot and I want to put a sphere in a designed position. How can I create a sphere? I expected to use patch? Can anyone help me to do this please?

Comment: What have you tried? Someone will be more likely to help you if you show your code and results or errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this:

Consider the center is at `[c1,c2,c3]`. The number of faces as `r`.

```
[x,y,z] = sphere(r);
surf(x+c1, y+c2, z+c3)
```

These two lines of code are enough to plot a sphere using the `surf` command.

For instance, if `C=[2,2,2]` and `r=30` the result is as follows:

[image]

This is a sphere of radius `1` centered at `[2,2,2]`. To have a sphere with an arbitrary radius `R`, you should multiply the `[x,y,z]` values by `R` before adding the center.

Comment: I believe your graph has `r=3`.

Comment: @ZX9 the radius is actually 1 unless you scale the sphere.